how to change button color when scroll on the top buttons
I have small issue, right now when I clicked the button is change the color but I need solution when I scroll the page and the buttons bar is fixed on top I would like to take the id from page to pass it into top buttons bar here is the CSS code and HTML code


$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var $el = $('.fixedElement');
  var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed) {
    $el.css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': '0px'
    });
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed) {
    $el.css({
      'position': 'static',
      'top': '10px'
    });
  }
});
// Just for testing, show all items
$('a.btn.continue').click(function() {
  $('li.items').show(400);
});
span {
  cursor: auto;
}

.number {
  margin: 100px;
}

.minus,
.plus {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #009688;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  height: 34px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.two-col-special {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.two-col-special li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* In case multi-word categories form two lines */
}

.two-col-special li:before {
  content: '+';
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* you can tweak the gap */
  color: orange;
  background-color: white;
  /* in case you want a color... */
  display: inline-block;
}

div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu p:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #323232;
}

body {
  font: 200 16px/1 sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-height: 10rem;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: 1s 0.4s;
}

#progress {
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  /* will be increased by JS */
  top: 50%;
}

#progstat {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: #009688;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(../fonts/DG-Heaven-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: mySecoundFont;
  src: url(../fonts/TheSansArab-Plain.ttf);
}

* {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}


/*            @font-face {
                            font-family: myFirstFont;
                            src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.woff2) format('woff2');
                        }
            
                        @font-face {
                            font-family: myFirstFont;
                            src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.woff2) format('woff2');
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }
            
                        * {
                            font-family: myFirstFont;
                        }*/

.button {
  background: #323232;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #323232;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 70px;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #009688;
  color: #9d7d08;
}

.button:focus,
.button:active {
  background: #3ab9a4;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #009688;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.sidemenubtn {
  background: #323232;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 0.05px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9d7d08;
  border-top: 0.05px solid #68a38e;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 1px;*/
}

.sidemenubtn:hover {
  background: #009688;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.05px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 0.05px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fixedElement2 {
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.fixedElement {
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="translate " id="groups2" onclick="closeNav()">
  <button id="16" class="button"><p>Foul</p></button>
  <button id="17" class="button"><p>Gelabah</p></button>
  <button id="18" class="button"><p>Salts Motabag</p></button>
  <button id="19" class="button"><p>Sweet Motabag</p></button>
</div>
<!-- -->
<h2 id="34" style="color: black;" class="menu-group">Foul</h2>
<div id="result" class="button.active" dir="ltr">
  <div id="undefined" class="menu-item translate ">
    <div class="menu-group">
      <h3 class="menu-item-heading ">
        <img onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,12.00,480)" id="itemimg" src="https://www.shorouknews.com/uploadedimages/Other/original/fhgdxhxdfhgdfhgxdf.jpg" alt="undefined" class="menu-item-img">
        <div>
          <!-- -->
          <span class="menu-item-name" style="text-align: center;" id="itemn">Foul with eggs</span>
          <p class="menu-item-desc"></p>
          <br><a><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:26px; padding-right: 50px;"></i></a>
          <a onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,12.00,480)"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:30px; padding-right: 40px;"></i></a></div>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<h2 id="34" style="color: black;" class="menu-group">Gelabah</h2>
<div id="result" class="button.active" dir="ltr">
  <div id="undefined" class="menu-item translate ">
    <div class="menu-group">
      <h3 class="menu-item-heading ">
        <img onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,6.00,690)" id="itemimg" src="https://i.postimg.cc/CxRnR0y9/قلابة.jpg" alt="undefined" class="menu-item-img">
        <div>
          <span class="menu-item-name" style="text-align: center;" id="itemn">Regular Gelabah</span>
          <p class="menu-item-desc">Gelabah Foul By hijazy way</p>
          <br><a><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:26px; padding-right: 50px;"></i></a>
          <a onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,6.00,690)"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:30px; padding-right: 40px;"></i></a></div>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<h2 id="34" style="color: black;" class="menu-group">Salts Motabag</h2>
<div id="result" class="button.active" dir="ltr">
  <div id="undefined" class="menu-item translate ">
    <div class="menu-group">
      <h3 class="menu-item-heading ">
        <img onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,10.00,290)" id="itemimg" src="https://i.ibb.co/Rj8rCBj/image.jpg" alt="undefined" class="menu-item-img">
        <div>
          <span class="menu-item-name" style="text-align: center;" id="itemn">Cream Cheese Motabag</span>
          <p class="menu-item-desc">Prepared by cream cheese</p>
          <br><a><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:26px; padding-right: 50px;"></i></a>
          <a onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,10.00,290)"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:30px; padding-right: 40px;"></i></a></div>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div id="result" class="button.active" dir="ltr">
  <div id="undefined" class="menu-item translate ">
    <div class="menu-group">
      <h3 class="menu-item-heading ">
        <img onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,10.00,530)" id="itemimg" src="https://i.ibb.co/k0X6cdW/image.jpg" alt="undefined" class="menu-item-img">
        <div>
          <span class="menu-item-name" style="text-align: center;" id="itemn">Vegetables Motabag</span>
          <p class="menu-item-desc">Prepared by a quality vegetables</p>
          <br><a><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:26px; padding-right: 50px;"></i></a>
          <a onclick="showItemsModalAr(undefined,10.00,530)"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" style="color: #3ab9a4; font-size:30px; padding-right: 40px;"></i></a></div>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



all what i need it just when scroll the button is change the color to the id which item is showing on the page

Where is the jQuery library? Avoid using inline on* like onclick attribute handlers. Avoid using inline style attributes (unless for passing CSS vars). a onclick ? No. use the preferred <button type="button"> instead. Anchors are not buttons. .click(function () { use the preferred .on("click", function () {

@RokoC.Buljan do you have a sample code ? and about the jQuery library i have it on the project I just need it when i scroll the page up or down to effect the top buttons by id and change the color to active color on CSS style

you're using "a.btn.continue" but there's no such button in your HTML Please create a [mcve] - currently that's not one, and your code does not reproduce as intended.

I've edited the snippet in the question to add jQuery 3.7.1 to it, so at least it doesn't throw an immediate error on running.

I solved the issue with this code


// this for scroll the page to change the color of groups
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.isInViewport = function () {
        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

        return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var lastElem = null;

// this lone for calling the class div 
        $('.menug').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
                lastElem = $(this);

            }
        });

        if (lastElem != null) {
            console.clear();
            console.log(lastElem.attr("id"));

// this variable for get div id when scroll
 
            var divID = lastElem.attr("id");

// this variable for get id by class name when scroll 
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.grSelected');

            elements.forEach(element => {
                // do something with each element
                element.id;

                if (divID == element.id) {
                    lastElem = $(this);
// this for change color if the div id is match with button id 
                    let rr = document.getElementById(element.id);
                    rr.id;
                    rr.style = " background: #3ab9a4; color: white; font-size: 15px; border: 1px solid #323232;  border-radius: 8px; height: 70px; width: fit-content; text-align: center;";
//                    console.log(rr);

                } else {
                    let rr = document.getElementById(element.id);
// this for change color if the div id is not matching with button id 

                    rr.id;
                    rr.style = " background: #323232; color: white; font-size: 15px; border: 1px solid #323232;  border-radius: 8px; height: 70px; width: fit-content; text-align: center;";
//                    console.log(rr);
                }
            });
        }
    }).scroll();
});




It is not at all clear how this code is related to the code in the question, let alone how it fixes it. Please use the Copy snippet to answer button to copy the snippet from the question into the answer, then edit the snippet and add the code. Please explain how the two work together to solve the issue.
